# Jenkins generate allure report with old json files

Tags: maven, jenkins, allure

I'm using 2.26.0 version of allure plugin in Jenkins.
I create a [job with next configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYppm.png) 
After I run it, I can't see nothing in [allure report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42uJH.png) in Jenkins.
Because when I run it from Jenkins it only create this files in folder ['allure-results'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAMVe.png)  in my folder project on my local machine. 
If I clean this folder manually and run my project local from NetBeansit, it will create the right .json files in folder ['allure-results'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8QYK.png). After that, I can generate my report from [cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRWBF.png) and I can see my beautiful report [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsvGq.png).

Why does Jenkins not generate the right .json files for allure report? 
How can I build my allure report with right .json files in Jenkins?

Thanks,
Anastasiia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of profile, that I used in pom.xml. 
I should to [delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZuOk.png).

Or to not delete it and just to set a profile in Jenkins:
-P${profileName}